Should the windows in my oriel bay be taller?
I'm currently having new windows installed... and things are looking a bit different to how I expected.
My expectation was that the windows would go all the way to to the top, sitting pretty much flush against the roof of the bay. But the fitters have added about half a foot of PVC/wood above the top of the window. Compare this to my neighbour on the right, whose window goes all the way to the top.
I'll bring this up with them tomorrow morning and they're a local/reputable firm that I trust. But looking for an unbiased perspective – am I right to question this? Is there any good reason for them to have to pad the top of the window like this?



I think it may be fair to question it, as you are the one having the work performed (unless the contract specifies the size of windows they did install, in which case, they did what they promised). My guess, and this is just a guess, is that they used a window size they had in stock or could more easily obtain. That said, I think the finish on your windows is more aesthetically appealing than that of your neighbor. You may get a tiny bit less light inside, but if you look at your neighbor's blinds, it looks like their blinds likely block any additional light their larger windows allow through.

@EndAntisemiticHate I agree—the neighbor's roof edge "wrap over" looks uglier than the OP's situation.

I hope that's closed-cell foam on the inside and not some cheap junk.

If I knew nothing about the situation and was asked, " Which installation is correct?" I would choose the OP's windows.

VtC as opinion based. There is no "should" in this situation - what is "right" is what's installed. If your contract said "replacement windows" then the contractor ordered stock sized windows to fit in the opening because they were cheaper. If it said "exact replacement windows", then they bought the wrong thing and need to swap them out. Either is fine, it's up to you to determine the look you want and pay for it, if there's a price difference.

@RMDman I agree from an aesthetic point of view, but I cannot support my preference beyond that.  Can you offer support beyond the aesthetics?  If so, I'm interested in learning (and likely the OP is as well).

@EAH, The new window having a definite facia would indicate the construction was more "stout".  That would lend an idea of better construction , thus a determination of "correct".  Again this is just my opinion, based on  the exterior view.
